# Incompatible shapes when fitting my CNN in Tensorflow (None, 1) and (None, 150) even after trying One-Hot Encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run a CNN that classifies 150 different Pokemon characters. Despite my best efforts, I continuously get this error:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 150) are incompatible`. I've tried one-hot encoding my labels (maybe I did it incorrectly?), but no dice. I know this is a popular issue but I can't seem to find a solution online that works for me. Here is the relevant code (I didn't include the imports here):

````
data_dir='/Users/liatkatz/Downloads/PokemonData'
classes=[]
for i in os.listdir(data_dir):
    classes.append(i)
for i in classes: #gets each folder
    os.makedirs(data_dir+'/train/'+i) #make a train folder that contains each class folder
    os.makedirs(data_dir+'/test/'+i) #make a test folder that contains each class folder
    source=data_dir+'/'+i #call each folder source
    every_file_name=os.listdir(source) #gets all contents from each folder
    np.random.shuffle(every_file_name) #shuffles the files
    test_ratio=0.2 #establish what percentage of files should be allocated to the test group
    train_file_names, test_file_names=np.split(np.array(every_file_name), [int(len(every_file_name)*(1-test_ratio))]) #splits the data according to the ratio
    train_file_names=[source+'/'+name for name in train_file_names.tolist()] #gets file path for each training file
    test_file_names=[source+'/'+name for name in test_file_names.tolist()]#gets file path for each test file
    for name in train_file_names:
        shutil.copy(name, data_dir+'/train/'+i) #copies each file into the training folder, then the class folder
    for name in test_file_names:
        shutil.copy(name, data_dir+'/test/'+i) #copies each file into the test folder, then the class folder
#Create a function to get all of the files
def listTheFiles(directory): #define function and parameter
    listOfFiles=os.listdir(directory)
    allFiles=list()
    for file in listOfFiles: #iterates over every file
        full_path=os.path.join(directory, file)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            allFiles = allFiles + listTheFiles(full_path)
        else:
            allFiles.append(full_path)
                
    return allFiles

#COLLECT TRAINING DATA
img_data=[]
img_labels=[]
img_size=(100,100)
errors=0

for i in classes:
    path=data_dir+'/train/'+str(i)
    images=os.listdir(path)
    for img in images:
        try:
            image=cv2.imread(path+'/'+img)
            image_fromarray=Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
            resize_image=image_fromarray.resize((img_size))
            img_data.append(np.array(resize_image))
            img_labels.append(i)
        except:
            print("Error in "+img)
img_data=np.array(img_data)
img_labels=np.array(img_labels)
#SHUFFLE TRAINING DATA
shuffle_indices=np.arange(img_data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(shuffle_indices)
img_data=img_data[shuffle_indices]
img_labels=img_labels[shuffle_indices]
#Split data
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val=train_test_split(img_data, img_labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42,shuffle=True)
X_train=X_train/255
X_val=X_val/255
y_train.shape
(3777,)
data_augment=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30,
                               zoom_range=.15,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               width_shift_range=15,
                               height_shift_range=15,
                                shear_range=.15,
                               fill_mode='nearest')
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Dense, Flatten, MaxPool2D, Dropout
input_shape=(100,100,3)
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())



model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(150, activation='softmax'))
lr = 0.001
epochs = 30

opt = Adam(lr=lr, decay=lr / (epochs * 0.5))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(data_augment.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32), epochs=5,validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-264-e28d03f78f8e> in <module>
----> 1 history=model.fit(data_augment.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32), epochs=5,validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    761     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    764             *args, **kwds))
    765 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3277     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3278     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3279         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3280             self._name,
   3281             self._python_function,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:155 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1643 categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4862 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 150) are incompatible```
````

Comment: Where exactly are you one-hot encoding your labels?

Comment: I deleted that code because it didn't yield any results. If there's a particular method you'd suggest please let me know.

Comment: You have to one-hot encode your labels, it will not work otherwise. You can use keras.utils.to_categorical.

Comment: I tried to one-hot encode the labels, but I get the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Magneton'

Comment: Your labels need to be integers in the range 0 to num_classes - 1

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to to transform your labels using [tf.keras.utils.to_categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical)

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=150)
```